# Why am I not seeing CKEditor buttons on prod?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Okay, so I configured the Full HTML text format and added some buttons to CKEditor locally in a Lando environment. Then I exported the configuration with `drush cex`, committed it, pulled and imported on production with `drush cim`. However, even though changes can be seen in `admin/config/content/formats/full_html`, buttons aren't there when creating content. Any ideas? I also cleared caches. I even changed permissions on `sites/default`recursively to 777 before clearing caches through the UI.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109834/discussion-on-question-by-kartagis-why-am-i-not-seeing-ckeditor-buttons-on-prod).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Drupal are you running?

Since the new button appears in `admin/config/content/formats/full_html` I guess the Config Import/Export worked but the connection between the new config and the CKEditor in the content didn't update?

I will try that on my setup since im working with drush cex and drush cim regularly.

Comment: I am on 8.9. I may have found the issue. I will post it as an answer after I confirm with my local installation.